# Compiling rtl8188ee driver fails

Tags: wireless, drivers, compiling, make

I am trying to compile and install the proprietary driver for my RTL8188ee Wireless card.
Using `make` in the download directory (`/home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013`) results in following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/build M=/home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
CC [M]  /home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
In file included from /home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:39:0:
/home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/pci.h:247:15: Fehler: expected »=«, »,«, »;«, »asm« or »__attribute__« before »rtl_pci_probe«
make[2]: *** [/home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/sebastian/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

What exactly is the problem and how can I fix it?

Using RaringX64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's clean up the file from your first attempt:

```
cd Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013
make clean
```

Now, let's modify one file:

```
gedit pci.h
```

At the top of the file, after the comment section all outlined in **, add this sequence:

```
#ifndef __devinit
#define __devinit
#define __devinitdata
#endif
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Now do:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Really `sudo make install`? Not `sudo checkinstall`?

Comment: Thanks, now it's working about 10 times faster than before.